# Maximized surface area of box with fixed length

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Assuming we have a box given that the sum of all intervals is $a$.
What is the maximal surface area of the box? 
I know I need to use Lagrange multiplier but when I find the hessian matrix I get that it is not defined. I get the following matrix:

$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
      0 & 2 & 2 & 4\\
      2 & 0 & 2 & 4\\
      2 & 2 & 0 & 4\\
      4 & 4 & 4 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
But it is neither positive nor negative defined. So for
              $$\left\{ x=y=z=\frac{a}{12}\right\}$$
I get... nothing? I am curtain that I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean the sum of the length of all sides is $a$? So $g(x,y,z)=4(x+y+z)-a$?

Comment: Yes exactly. And f is f(x,y,z)= 2xy + 2xz +2yz

Answer (score 0):

The Lagrange multiplier is

$$L=2(xy+xz+yz)+\lambda(a-(4x+4y+4z))$$

We can find the partial derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=2y+2z-4\lambda\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=2x+2z-4\lambda\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}=2x+2y-4\lambda\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}=a-(4x+4y+4z)\\
$$

You are correct that the critical point is $x=y=z=\frac{a}{12}$.
So the Hessian matrix is
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &4&4&4\\
4&0&2&2\\
4&2&0&2\\
4&2&2&0
\end{bmatrix}

The determinants $H_1=-16, H_2=64, H_3=-192$, which guarantees a maximum.